# Meta tag and Character Encoding on link

Tags: html, encoding, meta

I am using the following meta tag to encode a index.html page:

```
<head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

With the above tag I am able to proper display on my page characters like:

```
ç ã õ á
```

However whenever I send a link to the page through Facebook chat these characters are not displayed on the link description. As shown bellow:

-Right (What I need to show)

```
https://www.mypage.com/index.html

- A cool site full of weirds characters  like ç ã õ á
```

-Wrong (What I have now)

```
https://www.mypage.com/index.html

- A cool site full of weirds characters  like
```

How may I assure the encode will be right both on my page and on the link.

Answer (score 0):

ISO-8859-1 is a legacy encoding that was obsoleted last century by Unicode.

Presumably, Facebook only supports Unicode, so change the encoding of the document (not *just* the declaration about what encoding you are using) to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Facebook supports legacy encodings (I see no reason why they couldn't, given that they have a handful of hardware and engineers), changing a `<meta>` tag in your HTML does nothing to alter the character set the document is using. It's, at most, a fallback mechanism to detect the encoding if the page is saved to disk (something I don't think nobody still does). What really counts is the `Content-Type` HTTP header sent by the server and, even there, it's just a **declaration**. You still need to actually save your file with such encoding:

[image: Save as ISO-8859-1]

New projects written in the last decade should be using UTF-8. The only reason to use ISO-8859-1 is having a legacy codebase you can't afford fixing.